# PHP/MYSQLi - Display last date query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My database table have 5 columns: 'id', 'date_visited', 'page_title', 'ip' and 'total_views'.
I am not able to display ORDER BY 'date_visited'.
My PHP Query is:

```
<?php
[...]
$query = "SELECT *,count(*) FROM table WHERE ip GROUP BY page_title";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link). "Q=".$query);
if(!$result == 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $dataList_br .= '<tr>
                            <td>' .$row['date_visited']. '</td>
                            <td>' .$row['page_title']. '</td>
                            <td>' .$row['count(*)']. '</td>
                        </tr>';
    }
} else {
    $dataList_br .= '<p class="warning">No data found in database.</p>';
}
?>
```

When it outputs, it displays [date][page title] and [total views].
Please someone help me, how do I display last date from the query, instead now it displays the very first day the page was visited.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is lenient about the contents of the `GROUP BY` and will return a row for the group somewhat arbitrarily if columns aren't in the `GROUP BY`  but are `SELECT`ed. In your case, it just gave you the first row (lowest date) for each group.

Get the page_name of the row with the `MAX(date_visited)` per group and join that against the main table to pull in the remaining columns from the main table.

```
SELECT
  table.id,
  table.ip,
  table.total_views,
  maxdates.date_visited,
  maxdates.page_name,
  maxdates.thecount
FROM
  table
  JOIN (
    /* Subquery returns the aggregates to join against 
       the main table so other columns can be pulled in */
    SELECT 
      page_title, 
      MAX(date_visited) AS maxdate, 
      COUNT(*) AS thecount 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY page_title
  ) maxdates
    ON table.page_name = maxdates.page_name 
       AND table.date_visited = maxdates.maxdate
```

Comment: Wow, I have never seen anything like that, some super advanced sql code. Thank you Michael, the code above didn't really work "out of the box", but I was able to fix and make it running. Thank you for directing me toward this solution. If anyone will try this, do not forget to change $row['count(*)'] to $row['thecount'].

Comment: @crashtestxxx Whenever you use a calculation in your `SELECT` list, it is recommended to give it an alias to reference elsewhere in the query and in your application code.  `COUNT(*) AS thecount`

Comment: Thank you Mike. To make my code work I had to remove table.id and table.total_views, and replace maxdates.date_visited and maxdates.page_name with table.date_visited and table.page_name. Also where it says FROM table GROUP BY page_title, I had to modify it FROM table WHERE ip GROUP BY page_title.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `ORDER BY`. Like so:

```
$query = "SELECT *, count(*) 
            FROM table 
           WHERE ip 
        GROUP BY page_title 
        ORDER BY date_visited ASC";
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan, I have already tried this and for some reason it doesnt work.

Comment: @Michael has the correct answer here; you have to force the max value of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this whit "ORDER BY":

```
$query = "SELECT date_visited, page_title,count(*) FROM table WHERE ip ORDER BY page_title ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link). "Q=".$query);
if(!$result == 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $dataList_br .= '<tr>
                            <td>' .$row['date_visited']. '</td>
                            <td>' .$row['page_title']. '</td>
                            <td>' .$row['count(*)']. '</td>
                        </tr>';
    }
} else {
    $dataList_br .= '<p class="warning">No data found in database.</p>';
}
```

Comment: No Atmon, thank you for the try. It still outputs the the oldest date.